# What browsers support `overflow-y`?

Tags: html, css

From what I understand, `overflow-y` is a CSS3 selector. But at http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus, it doesn't have that selector shown, show I don't know what browsers support it.

First, are `overflow-y` and `overflow-x` actually CSS3 selectors?

Second, what browsers support them?

Comment: They aren't selectors, they're properties. http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html and http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-y

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, overflow-x and y are not CSS3 selectors. They are simply properties, similar to `overflow` but with direction restrictions.

From http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/overflow

> The CSS3 overflow-x and overflow-y
>   properties are partially supported in
>   Internet Explorer for windows versions
>   5 and 6 and fully supported in
>   Internet Explorer versions 7 & 8.
>   Safari 3+, Chrome 2+, Firefox 2+ and
>   Opera 9.5+ all support these
>   properties.

Answer (score 5):

The overflow-y and overflow-x are not CSS3-exclusive properties.

They are (partially) supported in Internet Explorer 6.x+, Firefox 1.5+, recent versions of Safari, the beta of Opera 9.5, and (of course) Google Chrome.

Source (same as @sidyll): http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/overflow

Comment: If you include where you found the information, you're more likely to get an up vote. :)