# testing support for overflow-y:auto in  browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

I want to test if a particular css property attribute is supported in the browser. For a css property, i can do it like

```
var overflowSupport = document.createElement("detect").style["overflow-y"] === ""
```

But what if i have to check for a particular class or attribute. For example, i want to test the support for

```
overflow-y:auto
```

and use it for scrolling a large div, where supported, and use iScroll at other places.

How can i do that? Pls help.

Comment: Are there any 'modern' browsers which don't support it?

Comment: `overflow` is supported in all browsers as part of CSS2 - do you specifically mean `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`? You should edit the title if so.

Comment: overflow-y:auto is not supported in kindle browsers which have android 2.3.3 at their base.

Comment: @ghostCoder Thanks. Didn't know that. Something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 8):

Kind of an old question, but I thought I'd share my finds here, especially because the code sample given by Inkbug does not work as you would expect.

### Overflow property support

`overflow-y` has been around since the CSS2.1 times (however it's been standardized pretty recently, [in the css3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow)). For that reason, the [support on desktop browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892010/what-browsers-support-overflow-y) is very decent.

Now, what you're asking here is whether or not the scrolling behavior actually works when we specify `overflow-y: scroll` on a particular element.

This behavior was introduced fairly recently in mobile browsers. More precisely, Apple introduced it in iOS 5 with a `-webkit` vendor prefix (see page 176 of [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/SafariCSSRef.pdf)).

I can't find specific info for Android though.

What I *can* say about support for `overflow-scrolling` (vendor prefixed or not):

- latest nexus7 (Android 4.1.1): yes
- Android 2.3.x: no
- iOS >= 5: yes
- iOS < 5: no

### Feature detection for scrolling-overflow

If you want to give scrolling behavior to an element, I would advise using feature detection.

Here's [a gist](https://gist.github.com/1292309) showing how you can detect this `scrolling-overflow` property (it's been  [integrated in Modernizr since](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css-overflow-scrolling.js)). If you don't want to use Modernizr, here is a simpler version that does pretty much the same:

```
/**
 * Test to see if overflow-scrolling is enabled.
 */

var hasCSSProperty = function(prop) {
    if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        return window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null)[prop];
    } else {
        return document.body.currentStyle[prop];
    }
};

var supportOverflowScrolling = function() {
    if (hasCSSProperty('overflow-scrolling') ||
        hasCSSProperty('-webkit-overflow-scrolling') ||
        hasCSSProperty('-moz-overflow-scrolling') ||
        hasCSSProperty('-o-overflow-scrolling')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false
    }
};
```

Comment: `overflow-y` is not part of CSS2. It was created by Microsoft at the time of CSS2 but only proposed to be standardized post-CSS2.1.

Comment: You're correct. Overflow property has been around for a while and from the [css3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow), we read _"The para above is from CSS 2.1. Need to check if the introduction of overflow-x/y changes anything."_

Answer (score 0):

When one assigns an invalid value to a dom style, it gets rejected. Therefore this should work:

```
var testOverflowEl = document.createElement( "x-test" );
testOverflowEl.style.overflowY = "auto";
var overflowSupport = testOverflowEl.style.overflowY === "auto";
```

Answer (score 0):

[Arnaud Brosseau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1698568/arnaud-brousseau)'s reply surely deserves the checkmark.

Anyway, consider also using **[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com)**.

Using their `addTest` and `testAllProps` API functions, you can easily check for any css property support:

```
Modernizr.addTest('overflow-y',function(){
    return Modernizr.testAllProps('overflowY'); /* camel case here */
});
```

Then you can check it with JavaScript:

```
if(Modernizr.overflowY){
    /* do something if supported */
}
```

but it will also add a class to the `<html>` tag, so that you can custom rules on CSS too:

```
.overflowY #element {
    /* style for browsers supporting overflow-y */
}
.no-overflowY #element {
    /* style for browsers NOT supporting overflow-y */
}
```