# Disable Pop Up Background Scroll

Tags: css

I have a page that when you click on a button, it opens a pop up. I'm trying to disable background scroll when the pop up is enabled.

So far, I found this code to work, but only on chrome.

```
html,
body  {
overflow-y: hidden;
height: 100%;
}
```

On safari, when the pop up is enabled, the background scroll is disabled, which is good! but when you click on the pop up, it scrolls you back to the top of the page on the background, on chrome it does not do this.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446822/testing-support-for-overflow-yauto-in-browsers

Comment: try with just `overflow:hidden` without the -y

Comment: or try - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469227/overflow-y-not-working-in-safari-inside-a-modal