# Css overflow-y: how to show only when needed

Tags: html, css

I'm adding the overflow-y parameter to "scroll" in my css in order to have scrolling bar in case of overflow..

My problem is that if the content is not overflowing - i'm still having the blank scroll bar.

How can i set the overflow to show the scrolling bar only when needed ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can set it to `auto`

```
overflow-y : auto;
```

It will only show scroll bar in case of overflow.

Refer : [What browsers support `overflow-y`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892010/what-browsers-support-overflow-y)

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned before, the way to do this is by setting:

```
overflow-y: auto
```

When setting the property to **auto**, the browser determines how to handle the content, but generally, **the scrollbar appears when it is required**.

You would greatly benefit from learning more about the overflow property. There is a great article [here](https://kolosek.com/css-overflow/) that explains it nicely.