# It's possible to have a vertical scrollable div with horizontal overflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm developing an interface which has a standard dashboard layout, with the sidebar used like a filters panel. Within this panel there are some combo-boxes in order to select various filter criteria. Usually some of the options are too long to be contained in the sidebar area, and I'm not able to see the entire option name, due to the horizontal overflow. This sidebar is already vertical scrollable and the only way  I've found to see the options outside the sidebar area is to set overflow to visible. BUT in that case I lose the vertical scroll bar.

There is a way to see ONLY the horizontal overflow and mantain the vertical scrollbar of the sidebar?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

You can set different values for overflow-x and overflow-y:

```
overflow-x : visible;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Watch out for browser support [What browsers support `overflow-y`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892010/what-browsers-support-overflow-y)