# Visible overflow on X axis, but auto/scroll on axis Y

Tags: html, css

To keep things neat and short:

https://jsfiddle.net/m53ockLu/

```css
.container {
  max-height: 500px;
  background: grey;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 150px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: red;
}

.element {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 20px;
  background: green;
}

.first {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background: pink;
}

.second {
  display: inline-block;
}

.second-absolute {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="first"></div>
      <div class="second">
        <div class="second-absolute"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">

    </div>
    <div class="element">

    </div>
    <div class="element">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to keep the red container scrollable on vertical axis, and at the same time make the purple (.second-absolute) element overflow this red container horizontally? I'm totally out of ideas, I thought that overflow-x & overflow-y should do the trick, but no dice.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can have overflow through the scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to keep the red container scrollable on vertical axis, and at the same time make the purple (.second-absolute) element overflow this red container horizontally?

No.

I tried Ethan's suggestion and couldn't get the purple box to visibly overflow the scrollbar:

```css
.container {
  max-height: 500px;
  background: grey;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: red;
}

.element {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 20px;
  background: green;
}

.first {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background: pink;
}

.second {
  display: inline-block;
}

.second-absolute {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="first"></div>
      <div class="second">
        <div class="second-absolute"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">

    </div>
    <div class="element">

    </div>
    <div class="element">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't think the browser will let you overflow the scrollbar, I even put z-index, explicitly said to visibly overflow, played around with the position property etc.

Consider this example of letting the content dictate the size:

```css
.container {
  max-height: 500px;
  background: grey;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  width: max-content;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: red;
}

.element {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.first {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  background: pink;
}

.second {
  display: inline-block;
}

.second-absolute {
  height: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="element">
      <div class="first"></div>
      <div class="second">
        <div class="second-absolute"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">

    </div>
    <div class="element">

    </div>
    <div class="element">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That seems to be the case. I'll accept your answer in couple of days, maybe somebody will come with some hacky solution.

Comment: @nouseforaname Yeah possibly someone might know a hack. It seems important to you I'll go look for dupes.

Comment: @nouseforaname https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699056/its-possible-to-have-a-vertical-scrollable-div-with-horizontal-overflow This question seems to be asking the same thing, no useful answers though

Answer (score 0):

You made the parent `div` `sidebar` have `overflow-x: scroll;`, `overflow-y: auto;`. Instead, make each child have its own overflow properties instead of the parent.

Comment: I'm trying this and doesn't seem to work