Overflow position: absolute child with a position: relative parent out of an overflow-y: auto grandparent
I'm looking for an html + css way to do this. I have a scrollable list where each item has a badge next to it, positioned with position: absolute as being half outside of the list-container. The list container needs to have overflow-y: auto but this makes anything unable to overflow out of the stacking context.
I tried z-indexing it higher, I don't think position: fixed will work since I need the badge to follow its corresponding item when the user scrolls through the list.


.overflow-y {
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  right: -5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
}
 <div class="overflow-y">
    <span class="relative">
      list-item
      <span class="absolute"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="relative">
      list-item
      <div class="absolute"></div>
    </span>
</div>




I don't think a pure CSS+HTML solution can have them scroll together while being outside the scroll container unless there are some crazy CSS hacks. I would either re-design or put them into a separate div outside and use JS to sync the scroll progress and positioning.

Your HTML doesn’t look right - div inside span. Could you correct that first, then make your code into a runnable snippet which shows the icons and some scrolling.

"overflow-y: auto but this makes anything unable to overflow out of the stacking context." - the problem is that CSS won't let you have overflow set on y with overflow visible on x. See e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71592906/visible-overflow-on-x-axis-but-auto-scroll-on-axis-y

Could you describe why the icons need to be outside the bounds of the element?

They need to be outside because that's the current design of the app. At the same time I'm supposed to make it scrollable on the y axis while letting elements on the x-axis overflow. I'm open to any solution at this point, js as well, as long as it doesn't involve a crazy event listener.

Are you allowed to alter the HTML?

Yes. As long as it visually stays the same.

So the scrollbar must be to the left of the icons?

Yes, I think that's the only way it kinda makes sense.
